# Reference NodeJS libs from locations other than "node_modules" without using relative path

Tags: node.js, import, npm, ecmascript-6, node-modules

Assuming that I have 2 folders for NodeJS libs ie "node_modules" and "somename_modules". The latter is the folder that stores internally developed libraries which are proprietary.

I know that when we reference using "import" or "require", the default location is always point to the path where "node_modules" folder reside in the project.

My question is, how do we add another default location to where "somename_modules" is located so that when we reference using "import" or "require" in ES6 source code it will always check for libs from both "node_modules" and "somename_modules"?

Example:

```
import somefunc from 'somelib' //it will search in './node_modules/somelib' and './somename_modules/somelib'
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not think, you can do this.

But you can register your internal libraries/modules in package.js (pointing to somename_modules folder), so that they can sit in node_modules when npm install is done. And then, import/require statements can work normally.

E.g.
Lets say, you have a module name 'mod1' inside somename_modules folder. I.e:
"/somename_modules/mod1"

Add below dependency in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "mod1": "file:/somename_modules/mod1",
},
```

In this case, mod1 needs to follow npm structure, like having a package.json file in it.

Comment: I used 'file:./my-path' ("." after file:)